# Why IF statement works when WHERE doesn't

Tags: if-statement, sas, where-clause

Can anyone tell me why this line doesn't work? It's in a datastep in a macro.

where 1*substr(Sample_ID,6,6)<201704; (ERROR: where clause requires numeric bla bla)

Whereas the same thing with an if statement works.

if 1*substr(Sample_ID,6,6)<201704;

Comment: Not sure why you're doing the conversion, anyway. `where substr(sample_id,6,6) < '201704'` would work just as well (and have just as many potential issues...)

Answer (score 5):

A `where` clause cannot do implicit conversion (number to character, or vice versa), whereas an `if` statement within the datastep can perform that conversion.

Your `where` clause should read :

`where=(input(substr(Sample_ID,6,6),8.) < 201704)`